# How do I use multiprocessing.Queue from a process with a pre-existing Pipe?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, queue, pipe

I am trying to use [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) from inside another process that was spawned with [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). I want to be able to communicate between this process and a new child process, but this "middle" process has a polling read on the pipe with *its* parent, which seems to block execution of its child process.

Here is my file structure:

**entry.py**

```py
import subprocess, threading, time, sys

def start():
    # Create process 2
    worker = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "-u", "mproc.py"],
            # When creating the subprocess with an open pipe to stdin and
            # subsequently polling that pipe, it blocks further communication
            # between subprocesses
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            close_fds=False,)
    t = threading.Thread(args=(worker))
    t.start()
    time.sleep(4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

**mproc.py**

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time, sys, threading

def exit_on_stdin_close():
    try:
        while sys.stdin.read():
            pass
    except:
        pass


def put_hello(q):
    # We never reach this line if exit_poll.start() is uncommented
    q.put("hello")
    time.sleep(2.4)


def start():
    exit_poll = threading.Thread(target=exit_on_stdin_close, name="exit-poll")
    exit_poll.daemon = True
    # This daemon thread polling stdin blocks execution of subprocesses
    # But ONLY if running in another process with stdin connected
    # to its parent by PIPE
    exit_poll.start()

    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')

    q = ctx.Queue()
    p = ctx.Process(target=put_hello, args=(q,))

    # Create process 3
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(f"result: {q.get()}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

My desired behavior is that when running `entry.py`, `mproc.py` should run on a subprocess and be able to communicate with its own subprocess to get the `Queue` output, and this *does* happen if I don't start the `exit-poll` daemon thread:

```sh
$ python -u entry.py
result: hello
```

but if `exit-poll` *is* running, then process 3 blocks as soon as it's started. The `put_hello` method isn't even entered until the `exit-poll` thread ends.

Is there a way to create a process 3 from process 2 and communicate between the two, even while the pipe between processes 1 and 2 is being used?

Edit: I can only consistently reproduce this problem on Windows. On Linux (Ubuntu 20.04 WSL) the `Queues` are able to communicate even with `exit-poll` running, but *only* if I'm using the `spawn` multiprocessing context. If I change it to `fork` then I get the same behavior that I see on Windows.

Comment: The typical answer to situations *like* this (aside from named files or pipes) is to use a server on localhost to pass messages. In that regard a `multiprocessing.Manager` can actually run as a server and have child processes connect to it in order to access proxies to shared objects (including Queues). You *might* be able to monkey patch `multiprocessing.Queue` to use an already existing pipe, but it would be very difficult. Typically they create their own pipe when they're first created

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I experimented with `multiprocessing.Manager`, but it turns out I was wrong about when the subprocess 3 was blocking.. it doesn't even start running until the polling thread ends. So I guess it may not be a problem of `Queue` creation, but rather `Process` creation?